# Selector not Working for ImageButton in android

Tags: android, xml, selector, imagebutton

my selector code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mmb11" ></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mmb1"></item>

</selector>
```

my xml file 4 layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mmb"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mmb1"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mmb1custom" 
            android:clickable="true"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mmb5"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mmb5custom" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mmb2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mmb2custom" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mmb4"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mmb4custom" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mmb3"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mmb3custom"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

when pressed it is not changing the image as it suppose to...
As u can see ,i tried setting the click.....but not working
there is no error when application runs....only it is not showing the pressed selector 4 buttons....
Thank in advance ...

Comment: Solution is to alter the line like this :
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/mmb11" ></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mmb1"></item>